# How can a host gatsby on my own server like express and build the website when i need to

Tags: node.js, express, gatsby, child-process

I’m going to build a website and a part of the website is only available to users that sign up on the website.

My goal is to utilize Gatsby’s speed for the content on the site which changes very infrequently and also give users the option to upload files, change their profile’s settings, ask questions about the published content on the site.

Now since a SSG website doesn’t talk back to a database (unless it’s on the front-end which I might explore how to do safely) I wont be able to do any of the above mentioned actions.

So what I was thinking is splitting up the website/application (running on one server):
Let Gatsby handle every page that doesn’t include any user input. And let a standard Node/Express server deliver the pages that include user input.

To go to the Gatsby page I need to have this in my application.

```
    app.use(‘/’,express.static(‘./gatsby/public’));
```

And to rebuild(Gatsby) I just do this.

```
    const { execFile } = require(‘child_process’);
    const child = execFile(‘gatsby’, [‘build’], {cwd: ‘./gatsby’}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
       throw error;
      }
      console.log(stdout);
    });
```

Now again, this works but I don’t know if this is a good solution (splitting up the website like this).

Sorry if the question is weird this is my first question here. To summarize this question, how can a host gatsby on my own server like express and build the website when i need to.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem

Comment: Personally I think it's overly-complex and will (probably) lead to headaches later when you decide you actually DO need some page served statically to interact with the database. Why not try caching those pages instead?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: To summarize this question, how can a host gatsby on my own server like express, and build the website when i need to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should explore using Gatsby more fully before you go down the route described above. It's far more than a traditional SSG. It's easy to mix static content and dynamic content on a Gatsby site, and arguably Gatsby has been designed from the get-go to support this use case.

Gatsby is React, so once the static content has rendered on the page Gatsby mounts a React app, and you're free to handle all your dynamic actions from that point on normally, as you would in any React app. Your Express app could become "just" an API server, rather than serving static files. And then you're freed up to hosting Gatsby on something properly suited, and fast, like Netlify.

Also you might find it worthwhile to render content that changes frequently statically too - it's fairly common practice to re-build and re-deploy Gatsby production sites on a loop, or in response to content changing on the backend. That gives you the best of both worlds - a fast static site even for "dynamic" content. Of course, content that's particular to a logged in user could never be static, so you'd need dynamic pages for that - as you suggest